# How do I find all products by a category in my JavaScript JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON array of products and related categories. How do I find all products by a certain category and put into new JSON array?

```
{  
    productName: 'product 01',   
categories:   
[{categoryName: 'category 02'},   
{categoryName: 'category 42'}]   
}
```

Comment: this is not a valid `json` can you post a valid one for correct data source

Comment: Is it a product array?

Comment: can you give a bigger array or json so we can ve a clear picture of how ur array or json looks like.

Comment: Sure, but l'll have to do it in later...going to bed. But the example above was suppose to illustrate that the JSON contained a collection of categories for a single product. Sorry JSON not valid. I'll fix it soon.

Comment: @Rod the json is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of these product objects, and want to make a new object where the keys are the categories, and the values are an array of the product in each category:

```js
var products = [{
  productName: 'product 01',
  categories: [{
    categoryName: 'category 02'
  }, {
    categoryName: 'category 42'
  }]
}, {
  productName: 'product 02',
  categories: [{
    categoryName: 'category 03'
  }, {
    categoryName: 'category 42'
  }]
}];

console.log(products);

var productsByCategory = {};

products.forEach(function(product, index){
  product.categories.forEach(function(category, index){
    var name = category.categoryName;
    if(name in productsByCategory) {
      productsByCategory[name].push(product);
    } else {
      productsByCategory[name] = [product];
    }
  });
});
                             
console.log(productsByCategory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` function. So if you have array of categories `categories` inside your object `data` you can do

`var filteredCategories = data.categories.map(function(cat) { 
    return cat === "your_category_search_Criteria" 
})`

The `cat` object inside map callback is your category item and `filteredCategories` wiil be also array but it will contain filtered result

Answer (score 1):

```
// Array for to put the found objects in.
var myCats = [];

// Iterate over the array of objects.
for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
   // Iterate over the properties of the single object.
   for (var j in field[i]["categories"]) {
     // Does it contain the searched categoryName? 
     //   'category02' in this case.
     if (field[i]["categories"][j]["categoryName"] === "category02") {
      // Make a deep clone of the object.
      //   Push the new object to to collector array.
      myCats.push(Object.create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(field[i]))));
    }   
  }
}

// Test
for (i = 0; i < myCats.length; i++) {
  console.log(myCats[i]);
}
```